# parent having padding for height and child not adopting its height?

Tags: html, css

I am having this issue

```css
.item {
  width: 800px;
  background: #000;
  display: table;
}
.text {
  float: left;
  padding: 30px 0;
  width: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.box {
  width: 200px;
  float: right;
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <span class="text">
    Whatever Whatever Whatever Whatever Whatever Whatever Whatever Whatever 
    Whatever Whatever Whatever Whatever Whatever Whatever Whatever Whatever 
    Whatever Whatever Whatever Whatever Whatever Whatever
  </span>
  <div class="box">asdsadasdasdasdasdsadasdasca wdasdw</div>
</div>
```

The box doesn't have the same height as its parent.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing

```css
.box {
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
}
```

And adding

```css
.box {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```css
.item {
  width: 800px;
  background: #000;
  display: table;
}
.text {
  float: left;
  padding: 30px 0;
  width: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.box {
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <span class="text">
    Whatever Whatever Whatever Whatever Whatever Whatever Whatever Whatever 
    Whatever Whatever Whatever Whatever Whatever Whatever Whatever Whatever 
    Whatever Whatever Whatever Whatever Whatever Whatever
  </span>
  <div class="box">asdsadasdasdasdasdsadasdasca wdasdw</div>
</div>
```